# Ab initio rollback

Tags: data-warehouse, ab-initio

I have an Ab-Initio plan consisting of more than one graphs in it. If the plan failed in one particular graph during its 6th phase, then how can the plan be restarted from the particular graph and that too from the beginning.

Note: Not for the last check point available in the .rec file.

In this case what should i do?

Comment: What is this? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the respective *.rec file from the run directory for the plan it was created. And rerun the graph. As it will not find any recovery file it will execute from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be that you can disable the remaining graphs by selecting them, right click and then select disable. Now when you run your plan, only the enabled process will run without having to rerun the entire process, hope this helps and in case it does, pleas check the tick mark on the left and mark it as a correct answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Abinitio provde excellent first-line support services for their customers. I would recommend you email them support@abinitio.com. From experience it helps if you state your co>op version and your gde version and package the graph in question and send that as well.